# sweetalert2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sweetalert2

I would love to use SweetAlert2. But, I can't get it work... I read various posts on stackoverflow. But, I couldn't solve my problem..

The [sweetalert2 github page](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2) says that I can include the stylesheet separately if desired by adding
 "sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.js"
& "sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css". 

 Or, include "import Swal from 'sweetalert2'"
and "const Swal = require('sweetalert2')".

So, I took the first approach and got the following error messages:

- GET file:///Users/HyejungLim/SaferTrip_JL/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.js
  0 () index.html:21
- GET file:///Users/HyejungLim/SaferTrip_JL/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css
  0 () index.html:22
- GET file:///Users/HyejungLim/SaferTrip_JL/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js
  0 () jquery.min.js:2 [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 120ms
  index.js:31
- Uncaught ReferenceError: swal is not defined

  - at HTMLDivElement. (index.js:31)
  - at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
  - at HTMLDivElement.y.handle (jquery.min.js:2)

You can see the last error message after clicking the green button and one of circles.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test').click(function(){
  $(".options:hidden").fadeIn()
    .on("click", function(){
      $(this).css("background", "#F3C78D");
    })
    .on("click", function(){
      swal({
        title: 'Sweet!',
        text: 'Modal with a custom image.',
        imageUrl: 'https://unsplash.it/400/200',
        imageWidth: 400,
        imageHeight: 200,
        imageAlt: 'Custom image',
        animation: false
      })
     });
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Poor Story', sans-serif;
}

#test{
   cursor: pointer;
   display: block;
   text-align: center;
   position: absolute;
   display: flex;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%; 
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.options {
    background: #f7f7f5;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #F3C78D;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.options span {
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%; 
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#option1{
    transform: translate(-100%, -150%);
}

#option2{
    transform: translate(-160%, -40%);
}

#option3{
    transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}

#option4{
    transform: translate(60%, -40%);
}

#option5{
    transform: translate(15%, -150%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap 4.1.x -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poor+Story" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- sweetalert2 -->
  <script src="sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
<!-- You can also include the stylesheet separately if desired: -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.0/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css">
  
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" id="test">test</button>
    <div class="options" id="option1"><span>Hello<br>World</span></div>
    <div class="options" id="option2"><span>Goodbye</span></div>
    <div class="options" id="option3"><span>How<br>are<br>you?</span></div>
    <div class="options" id="option4"><span>Fine</span></div>
    <div class="options" id="option5"><span>Okay</span></div>
  </div>
</body>
<footer>
  <!-- Bootstrap 4.0 : jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</footer>
</html>
```

As suggested in the official page, I tried the second approach, which is adding
"import Swal from 'sweetalert2'"
and "const Swal = require('sweetalert2')"
in a JavaScript file.
So, I did and got the following error messages:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

due to "import Swal from 'sweetalert2'".

Also, none of JavaScript code worked, which was showing five circles after clicking the green button.

In conclusion, the second try caused more issues for me.
How could I make sweetalert2 work? Please give me any advice. Thanks in advance!

Comment: When I type "npm list" in terminal, I see "sweetalert2@7.26.9". So, I think I installed it properly.

Comment: Also, someone suggested adding "window.swal = require('sweetalert2');" at https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/javascript/sweetalert-swal-is-not-defined-after-npm-install. But, I got "ReferenceError: require is not defined" error message...

Comment: I accepted suggest edit changing from "sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.js" to "  <https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.0/sweetalert.min.js>
". It works now. But, I get error messages for other sweet2 links. I guess I have very little understanding of programming...

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 Problems in your case.

1. The Jquery CDN link is placed after sweetheart Link.put the jquery CDN link above Sweetalert instead of footer.
2. use 'S' in uppercase  Swal({
       title: 'Sweet!',.

Comment: Using 'S' in uppercase gave me an error: "index.js:31 Uncaught ReferenceError: Swal is not defined". 's' in lowercase works for me.

Comment: Also, I solved the issue by using the following: <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7.12.15/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script> and 
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7.12.15/dist/sweetalert2.min.css'>

Comment: oh, interesting! I couldn't make it work in my situation. Thanks for providing the jsfiddle link. :)